# How to make a global domain message in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In the web application that I'm building, there are several messages that are not specific to a bundle. Therefore I was thinking about putting them in 'app/Resources/translations/EPCommon.en.yml'.

The problem is that I don't know how to call this domain message in Twig. I tried some stuff but it doesn't work.

```
title="{{'share.facebook'|trans()}}"
title="{{'share.facebook'|trans({}, 'EPCommon')}}"

Result : title="share.facebook"
```

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

*EDIT : The yml file, in case there is something wrong in it.*

```
# app/Resources/translations/EPCommon.en.yml
share:
    facebook: "Share on Facebook"
    google: "Share on Google+"
    twitter: "Share on Twitter"
help:
    button: "Help"
```

Comment: Cleared the cache after adding the file?

Comment: Yes Pazi, I did but doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I found the solution ! It appears that translations catalogs are stored in a file name "/app/cache/dev/translations/catalogues.en.php" (for "dev" environment / "en" locale). For some reason my EPCommon catalog wasn't in there even after clearing the cache.

So I manually deleted the "app/cache/dev" and let it regenerate and now it works.

Thanks to you all.